# Adding some custom methods to delayed job in rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, model, delayed-job

I want to add some custom methods to the delayed jobs model.

I want to have some extra such as...

```
def status
  return "errored" unless self.last_error.blank?
  return "waiting" if self.locked_at.blank?
  return "running" unless self.locked_at.blank?
  return "blerg" if some.other.things...
end
```

...on the the delayed job class.

I was just wondering how I extend it in such a way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the class `Delayed::Job`? You can add methods to classes in a few ways in ruby, but probably the easiest way is:

**`config/initializers/delayed_job.rb`**

```
class Delayed::Job
  def status
    return "errored" unless self.last_error.blank?
    return "waiting" if self.locked_at.blank?
    return "running" unless self.locked_at.blank?
    return "blerg" if some.other.things...
  end
end
```

Although this might look like it overwrites the class, it actually just adds the method if the class is already loaded..

Comment: Jon, I am puzzled how you named this file, and where you placed it? I have tried /lib, /models, /models/concerns, etc, and noting is working.

Comment: Update: I was able to extend Delayed_Job, via /config/initializers/delayed_job_extension.rb